# Chinese punctuation not showing in output

Tags: xetex, cjk, xecjk

Does anyone know how to get the following Chinese character to display?

[image: Chinese punctuation]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{zhnumber}
\usepackage{cjknumb}
\setCJKmainfont{標楷體}

\begin{document}
This does not display: ○

\zhdigits{2015}

\CJKdigits{2015}

\end{document}
```

PDF output using XeLaTeX:

[image]

Comment: What is the encoding of your .tex file?  What editor are you using?

Comment: UTF-8 without BOM; TeXnicCenter 2.02, which supports UTF-8

Comment: Try http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/ or another PDF dumper- is the white circle in the pdf but not showing, or missing from the PDF entirely?  Also try putting the character in a box and running `\showbox` to see what TeX thinks it's setting.  Note that the symbol is a different character from the ideographic zero.